# How to sort from greatest to smallest of groupby data in Pandas Python

Tags: pandas

I would like to sort the number of occurrences that both the street `name` + `cross` name appear together from largest to smallest.

```
dataset=df.groupby(['Street Name', 'Cross Street']).size()
```

How do I sort this list in a Pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It returns a Series so you can use the `sort_values` method of the Series:

```
df.groupby(['Street Name', 'Cross Street']).size().sort_values()
```

Or, in descending order:

```
df.groupby(['Street Name', 'Cross Street']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use seaborn countplot with the grouped data

```
filter=team_wins_df['Playoffs']>0
grouped=team_wins_df[filter].groupby(['Team'])['Playoffs'].sum()
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
grouped.sort_values().plot.barh(ax=ax)
plt.title("Playoff count by team")
plt.show()
```